# Can some draw lifecycle of Fragment and its parent FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-fragmentactivity

In Android docs, I found a specs on `Activity` lifecycle and on `Fragment` lifecycle individually, but never together. It does not seem obvious as I attached a debugger to `FragmentActivity` which hosts my fragment, and the life cycle is more than crazy. It looks like activity finishes first and then fragments starts, which is impossible.

**Fragment's lifecycle**
[image]

---

**Activity's lifecycle**
[image]

---

Logically, fragment should "jump into" activity's lifecycle after its `onResume` and it would end before activity's `onPause`, but **it seems** it is not happening.

Can someone either show me the lifecycle of the fragment in connection to its parent's activity or direct me to some good tutorial on this?

Comment: Take a look at the video link, he explains about how activity lifecycle mingle with fragment lifecycle. This helped me hope others  will be helped too. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vk7VKUFOlbY

Comment: @mask this is great video!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle)? Fragment is created after Activity is created. It doesn't seem possible for "activity finishes first and then fragments starts" Can you post the code for that? 
This is what I tested, 1 FragmentActivity , two Fragments :[image]

Comment: Sure I did, it is was the 1st doc. But they never made a connection to its parent's life cycle. It seems I would have to do it myself...