# action bar Menu Item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

in my app I have a refresh button. clicking on it it rotates (animation) while the fragment is updating. suppose I navigate from the given fragment to another and then back. Is there any possibility when I navigate back  the refresh Menu Item  being clicked automatically without pressing on it.

menu item onclick method

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_refresh:

            item.setActionView(getAnimation());

            getCurrency(code,item);
            mViewpager.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Log.i("TAG", "refresh pressed =>");
            return true;
        }

        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I want this code to execute when navigating back without pressing the menu Item

Comment: i think you nee `mybutton.performClick();`, you can call that in `onRestart` method

Comment: yes that's correct but I need reference to the menu item in onRestart method, how to get that?

Comment: try `onOptionsItemSelected(menu.findItem(R.id.action_id));`

Comment: In `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method find your menuItem from menu and save it as a field of your class: `this.item = menu.findItem(R.id.my_menu_item);`

Comment: in which part it"s better to call it? I have a fragment

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941584/can-some-draw-lifecycle-of-fragment-and-its-parent-fragmentactivity

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can execute all the actions your are doing when the `optionMenu` creation method starting from the `animation` and the real updating as following:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_options_menu, menu);

     //Perform the updating action 
     item.setActionView(getAnimation());

        getCurrency(code,item);
        mViewpager.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Log.i("TAG", "refresh pressed =>");
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

      return true;
}
```

Comment: how this help OP for **refresh Menu Item being clicked automatically without pressing on it**?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan You can ask him this question. He asked how can he do this and I told him a way to do that