# Activity and Fragment onCreate call order

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm using a `Fragment` inside an `Activity`. The `Fragment` has an `OnInitListener` interface, in order to pass data to the host `Activity`, which is called inside it's `onCreate()` method. The issue is that some times (generally when the screen is locked and unlocked) I get a `NullPointerException` from an object that it is initialled on the `Activity#onCreate` Here's the code:

```
// Activity
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // ...some code...

    myObject = new MyObject();
}

@Override
public void onInit(ObjectProperty property) {
    myObject.setProperty(property);   // Here I get NullPointerException
}


// Fragment
public void onCreate() {
     // ... some code ...

     property = new ObjectProperty();
     listener.onInit(property);
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    listener = (OnInitListener) activity;  // This part is actually surrounded by try/catch, so don't worry about it
}
```

In summary, `Fragment` should initialise an object and pass it to the listener, so the `Activity` can set it to another object.

I'm guessing the problem is that `Fragment#onCreate` is being called before `Activity#onCreate()` and that's why I'm getting `NPE` but I could be wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941584/can-some-draw-lifecycle-of-fragment-and-its-parent-fragmentactivity

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it for the `onCreate()`, but I think the fragments `onCreate()` will always be later the the activity's `onCreate()`. If I make a fragment I always use `onActivityCreated()`. This is called after the activity is created.

Comment: Activity onCreate() will always be called first and then onAttach() fallowed with onCreate() of Fragment.

Comment: @PratikGoyal thanks for the reply, but why not use `onActivityCreated()`?